# Finding and differentiating with respect to variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a list of polynomials in `x1,x2,x3,y,z,t`. I want to differentiate each list element (polynomial) recursively with respect to all `xi` until they vanish in the polynomial. For example, if I have the polynomial

```
p = x1 x3^2 y t + x2 y^2 + x1^3 z t + x1 x2 y z + x1^2 x2 y t
```

then I differentiate with respect to `x1,x1,x2` and get `2*y*t`. Alternatively, I could differentiate with respect to `x3, x3, x1` and get the same result. So the final expression does not contain `xi`.
Any idea how to do that is appreciated.

Comment: `Variables` and `CoefficientRules` might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, still unclear how I can manage the above.

Comment: I didn't revert anything. Why isn't it a polynomial?

Comment: OK. I have now used the * notation for multiplication.

Comment: Ah, okay, that it was because we submitted the edits almost at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may employ `CoefficientRules` to obtain the coefficients of the polynomial with respect to `x1`, `x2`, `x3`.

```
p = x1 x3^2 y t + x2 y^2 + x1^3 z t + x1 x2 y z + x1^2 x2 y t;
r = CoefficientRules[p, {x1, x2, x3}]
```

> {{3, 0, 0} -> t z, {2, 1, 0} -> t y, {1, 1, 0} -> y z, {1, 0, 2} -> 
>     t y, {0, 1, 0} -> y^2}

For example, `{2, 1, 0} -> t y` means that the coefficient of `x1^2 x2^1 x3^0` is `t y`. We only have to correct for the factors that arise due to differentiation. This can be done as follows:

```
r[[All, 2]] *= Times @@@ (r[[All, 1]]!);
r
```

> {{2, 1, 0} -> 2 t y, {1, 1, 0} -> y z, {1, 0, 2} -> 2 t y, {0, 1, 0} -> y^2, {0, 0, 0} -> t x^3 z}

Comment: Thanks. So the differentiation result will be the sum of those coefficients? Also, I am getting the error "Part 2 does not exist" for the second command.

Comment: " So the differentiation result will be the sum of those coefficients?" Nope. Each of the values in the final list  is a result of a separate differentiation.

Comment: But I need the polynomial differentiated with respect all `xi` and have the result as a polynomial without `xi` as in my example.

Comment: That's what the code above provides. There are no `xi` left.

Comment: OK, but I'm getting an error: Part 2 does not exist

Comment: That means that you have not executed the code to produce `p`. Please try again.

Comment: _Sigh._ From your very own input. It is probably a typo.

Comment: Yes, I realised and corrected :) Great thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If I have functions as well as polynomials of these variables, say f1[x,y,t,], f2[x,t], etc. I would like to have these differentiated with the variables so f1`[x,y,t], etc. will appear in the answer. However they won't because I am considering coefficients only. Any thoughts how this can be possible?

Comment: @Bran That sounds as if you want to know more about `Series` and `SeriesCoeffient`: They compute Taylor series and their coefficients.